# Jquery onclick Navigation Previous Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, navigation

I'm new in Javascript and try to implement an next/previous (loop) button to a portfolio website. I managed to make the "next" button work correctly but cannot find the way to get the previous one right. I have tried a bit everything but end up with no solution.

So on, in my HTML part, I have those classes where Im loading other files according to the menu + the buttons:

```
<button class="paginate pt-trigger2"><i>PREVIOUS</button>
<button class="paginate pt-trigger3"><i>NEXT</button> 

<div class="pt-page pt-page-2" id="cadrage"><div class=contiennement> </div></div>
<div class="pt-page pt-page-3" id="cadrage"><div class="contiennement"> </div></div>
```

and on the Jquery side, here is the script I have included:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var arr = ["home.php","photo.php","websites.php","identity.php","illustration.php","about.php"];

var index = 1;  

var pagess = [".pt-page-1",".pt-page-2",".pt-page-3",".pt-page-4",".pt-page-5",".pt-page-6"];

$('.pt-trigger2').click(function(){ 
 $(".pt-page").html("");
 $('.pt-page').fadeIn(500);
     $(pagess[index]).load(arr[index]); 
    index = (index-1) % arr.length ;
 });

  $('.pt-trigger3').click(function(){ 
 $(".pt-page").html("");
$('.pt-page').fadeIn(500);
    $(pagess[index]).load(arr[index]); 
    index = (index+1) % arr.length ;
 });

});
<script>
```

So On, everything works fine exept wherever I am on the site, the previous button loads the content that is in .pt-page-2 ( photo.php )

Sorry for the newbiness, I try to do the best I can.

Thanks in advance Dear Cyberspace.

Comment: your two `.pt-page` divs have the same id `cadrage`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the kind of solution you'd be looking for...

There is a plugin designed to do this. http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

It loops through content and allows you to specify navigation links, transition effects etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out your [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ozgureffe/BzUdu/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var pageArray = ["home.php", "photo.php", "websites.php", "identity.php", "illustration.php", "about.php"];

    var currentPage = 0,

        loadPage = function (pageNum) {

            var pageArrayLength = pageArray.length;

            $('.pt-trigger:disabled').prop('disabled', false);

            if (pageNum <= 0) {
                pageNum = 0;
                $('.pt-trigger_prev').prop('disabled', true)
            }

            if (pageNum >= pageArrayLength - 1) {
                pageNum = pageArrayLength - 1;
                $('.pt-trigger_next').prop('disabled', true)
            }

            //Edit this part as you wish
            $('#cadrage').html('The contents of ' + pageArray[pageNum] + ' will be loaded here');


            //Until Here

            currentPage = pageNum;
        };

    $('.pt-trigger_prev').on('click', function () {
        loadPage(currentPage - 1)
    });

    $('.pt-trigger_next').on('click', function () {
        loadPage(currentPage + 1)
    });

    loadPage(currentPage)

});
```